# Is it possible to disable the OpenFileDialog cancel button?

Tags: c#, winforms, fileopendialog

Is it possible to set the OpenFileDialog's cancel button enable = false? If so, How?

*I'm using winforms*

**Edit**

```
OpenFileDialog file_open_dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? A simple line of code showing how you are opening your dialog box now would be very helpful. I have no idea if you are talking about a file dialog box or some class called OpenDialog or a method of some other class called OpenDialog. If you are talking about a Form object the method is ShowDialog(), not OpenDialog(), so I really have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @ Dan :(+1) Why can't we go for a Custom control(A custom control for `OpenFileDialog` (overriding the existing `openFileDialog`))

Comment: You probably want to check out these articles: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996463.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx

Comment: @Pramodh i think its not possible to override an existing openfiledialog usercontrol.

Comment: @ Rye : Try with `Windows Forms Control Library`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe so, and with good reason! Are you *sure* that you want to disable the Cancel button? Being that this is a modal dialog this would prevent the user from continuing (and hence making your application unusable) until they selected a file - there are almost certainly going to be scenarios where this simply isn't possible, or the user doesn't want to be forced into saving a file.

Of course I could be wrong and there could be a completely legit scenario that I'm not aware of - however I'm afraid that Microsoft were also unaware of this scenario and so the OpenFileDialog doesn't support disabling the cancel button.

I'm afraid that if you really don't want a cancel button you will need to create your own clone of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

handle the cancel in a loop if you want? might frustrate users ;)

```
do
  {}
while (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK);
```